# Entity Framework extension method ICollection / IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to check the same specific condition (`where` clause) many times:

```
return _ctx.Projects.Where(p => p.CompanyId == companyId &&
                          (p.Type == Enums.ProjectType.Open || 
                           p.Invites.Any(i => i.InviteeId == userId))).ToList()
```

The part after the '&&' will cause that the user isn't able to retrieve restricted projects.

I wanted to abstract this check to a function. In the future these conditions could change and I don't want to replace all the LINQ queries.

I did this with the following extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<Project> IsVisibleForResearcher(this IQueryable<Project> projects, string userId)
{
    return projects.Where(p => p.Type == Enums.ProjectType.Open || 
                               p.Invites.Any(i => i.InviteeId == userId));
}
```

Now I can change the LINQ query to:

```
return _ctx.Projects.Where(p => p.CompanyId == companyId)
                    .IsVisibleForResearcher(userId).ToList()
```

This generates the same SQL query. Now my problem starts when I want to use this extension method on another DbSet that has projects.

Imagine that a company has projects. And I only want to retrieve the companies where the user can at least see one project.

```
return _ctx.Companies
       .Where(c => c.Projects.Where(p => 
            p.Type == Enums.ProjectType.Open || 
            p.Invites.Any(i => i.InviteeId == userId))
       .Any())
```

Here I also like to use the extension method.

```
return _ctx.Companies
       .Where(c => c.Projects.AsQueryable().IsVisibleForCompanyAccount(userId).Any())
```

This throws following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   Remotion.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not parse expression 'c.Projects.AsQueryable()': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable' is currently not supported.

Than I created the following extension methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<Project> IsVisibleForResearcher(this ICollection<Project> projects, string userId)
{
    return projects.Where(p => p.Type == Enums.ProjectType.Open || 
                               p.Invites.Any(i => i.InviteeId == userId));
}
```

But this didn't work also.

Does anyone has an idea?
Or a step in the right direction.

Btw I'm using Entity Framework Core on .NET Core

**UPDATE**:

Using a `Expression<Func<>>` resulted in the same exception:

> 'System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable' is currently not supported.

**UPDATE 2**

Thx @ivan-stoev for providing a solution.
I still have one problem. I also want to retrieve the count of 'visible' projects.

I fixed it by doing this:

```
var companies = _ctx.Companies
                .WhereAny(c => c.Projects, Project.IsProjectVisibleForResearcher(userId))
                .Select(c => new CompanyListDto
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    LogoId = c.LogoId,                   
                    ProjectCount = _ctx.Projects.Where(p => p.CompanyId == c.Id)
                                       .Count(Project.IsProjectVisibleForResearcher(userId))     
                });
```

But I don't find a way to just use `c.Projects` instead of `ctx.Projects.Where(p => p.CompanyId == c.Id)`

The SQL that gets generated is correct, but I'd like to avoid this unneeded check.

Sincerely,
Brecht

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using expressions / custom methods inside the `IQueryable<T>` query expression has been always problematic and requires some expression tree post processing. For instance, [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) provides `AsExpandable`, `Invoke` and `Expand` custom extension methods for that purpose.

While not so general, here is a solution for your sample use cases w/o using 3rd party packages.

First, extract the expression part of the predicate in a method. The logical place IMO is the `Project` class:

```
public class Project
{
    // ...
    public static Expression<Func<Project, bool>> IsVisibleForResearcher(string userId)
    {
        return p => p.Type == Enums.ProjectType.Open ||
                    p.Invites.Any(i => i.InviteeId == userId);
    }
}
```

Then, create a custom extension method like this:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T, E>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<E>>> elements, Expression<Func<E, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var body = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new Type[] { typeof(E) },
            elements.Body, predicate);
        return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, elements.Parameters));
    }
}
```

With this design, there is no need of your current extension method, because for `Projects` query you can use:

```
var projects = _ctx.Projects
    .Where(p => p.CompanyId == companyId)
    .Where(Project.IsVisibleForResearcher(userId));
```

and for `Companies`:

```
var companies = _ctx.Companies
    .WhereAny(c => c.Projects, Project.IsVisibleForResearcher(userId));
```

**Update:** This solution is quite limited, so if you have different use cases (especially inside the `Select` expression as in your second update), you'd better resort to some 3rd party package. For instance, here is the LinqKit solution:

```
// LInqKit requires expressions to be put into variables
var projects = Linq.Expr((Company c) => c.Projects);
var projectFilter = Project.IsVisibleForResearcher(userId);
var companies = db.Companies.AsExpandable()
    .Where(c => projects.Invoke(c).Any(p => projectFilter.Invoke(p)))
    .Select(c => new CompanyListDto
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        Name = c.Name,
        LogoId = c.LogoId,
        ProjectCount = projects.Invoke(c).Count(p => projectFilter.Invoke(p))
    });
```

Comment: Totally works! Thank you very much for this answer! Have a nice day!
Going to study the solution a bit so the next time I need it I can produce something like this myself.

Comment: Still have a small problem. I posted it as an 'Update 2' in my original question. SQL that gets generated is correct but I don't like the way I had to do it. Don't feel yourself obligated to check!

Comment: No problem checking it. The problem is that the solution is quite limited (as I mentioned in the beginning) - just for top level queryables. Once you need another method (nested `Where`, `Count` etc.) and especially inside a `Select` like in your update, you'll find that your need more and more helpers. Probably you really have to look at AutoMapper for projection (`ProjectTo`) and/or LinqKit for expression composition.

Comment: Your update did the trick! Was trying it myself but I didn't know that LinqKit requires expressions in variables. You saved my day (again)!

Comment: Please note with LinqKit you can use c.Projects directly (the projects expression is unnecessary) and change `projects.Invoke(c).Any(p => projectFilter.Invoke(p))` to `c.Projects.Any(projectFilter.Compile())`